# scaled item goes outside viewport

Tags: css

I have a little library of images and I'm creating effects to view them larger, using `transform: scale()`.

The problem is that, in lower resolutions, when I click on an image that's near the viewport a part of it goes outside the viewport.

I'd like to find a solution that positions the item inside the viewport, maintaining the scale effect (or any other scale-like effect/approach).

This is the markup:

```
<article>
  <input type="checkbox" id="g1" hidden>
  <label class="lightbox" for="g1"><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/640x420" alt=""></label>
  <input type="checkbox" id="g2" hidden>
  <label class="lightbox" for="g2"><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/640x420" alt=""></label>
  <input type="checkbox" id="g3" hidden>
  <label class="lightbox" for="g3"><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/640x420" alt=""></label>
  <input type="checkbox" id="g4" hidden>
  <label class="lightbox" for="g4"><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/640x420" alt=""></label>
</article>
```

And the CSS:

```
article { display: flex; flex-wrap: wrap }
article > label {
    display: block;
    width: calc(25% - 10px);
    margin: 5px;
    overflow: hidden;
            transition: .5s transform;
         -o-transition: .5s transform;
        -ms-transition: .5s transform;
       -moz-transition: .5s transform;
    -webkit-transition: .5s transform;
}
article > label > img {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
}
article > label > img:hover {
    cursor: zoom-in;
    opacity: .6
}
input[type="checkbox"]:checked + label {
    transform: scale(2.5);
    z-index: 1;
}
input[type="checkbox"]:checked + label > img:hover {
    cursor: zoom-out;
    opacity: 1
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/c5syoy4x/

Maybe there's a better approach for what I'm trying to do?

Comment: adjust transform-origin

Comment: I've been trying it, but it only works for some images, for example for the images at the right, the ones at the left go outside... Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: each one should have a specific transform-origin

Comment: Right, that's it, I've completely forgot about classes... Thanks!